# The Dancing Dead

Tags: music-video, dancing

**[Music Fans Topic Challenge #2 - Dancing](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403/music-fans-topic-challenge-2-dancing)**

---

Michael Jackson's [*Thriller*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOnqjkJTMaA) music video was arguably the most influential music video ever, and its iconic zombie dance has been widely imitated in popular culture.  But the trope of the dancing dead (*["Danse Macabre"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danse_Macabre)*) is far older.

I know of several subsequent (mainstream) music videos featuring the dancing dead --My Chemical Romance's ["Helena"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCCyoocDxBA), the Dixie Chicks' ["Goodbye Earl"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gw7gNf_9njs) and Flying Lotus' ["Never Catch Me,"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lXD0vv-ds8) to name a few of the best.  But were there any *before* "Thriller"?  If so, what was the first music video to feature the dancing dead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say with certainty, but an early candidate is from Disney's "Silly Symphonies" cartoons from 1929.  In the example below, we have a Iwerks, Clark & Jackson cartoon devoted to a dance of the skeletons.  Music is by Carl Stalling and adapts Edvard Grieg's "March of the Dwarfs".

[Silly Symphony #1 - The Skeleton Dance (1929)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOGhAV-84iI)